# Not equal boto3 filter

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I want to describe security groups which don't have a default as a group name!

```
SGresponse = client.describe_security_groups(  
    Filters=[
        {
            'Name': 'vpc-id',
            'Values': [vpcids]
         },
         {
        'Name': 'group-name',
        'Values': default
        }
     ]
 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such negation in Boto3 filters unfortunatly.

You will have to loop on the results and remove the security groups that you don't need yourself.